# Handling request after installing MAMP (no DNS setup yet)

Tags: apache, localhost, mac, mamp

I've just installed MAMP on my mac machine and checked the server is working by looking at localhost. I looked up my IP address by `ifconfig`. When I use another machine, I still can't get connected to the server. Why is that? I haven't register a domain name, but I suppose to be able to connect by IP address, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. I know on WAMP you have to edit your Apache conf file to allow other computers to access your websrever. This is for security reasons as software like WAMP and MAMP are not configured to be secure by default.

Somewhere in your main Apache conf file you'll find where access is controlled. Change it to be something like this and it *should* work for you (after restarting Apache):

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files/*/www">
 Order allow, deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Obviously you'll need to change the path to be appropriate to your Mac install.

*(Hopefully someone with MAMP experience can improve my answer appropriately)*